# Read data received from specific port C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, serial-port, port

iam using 'traccar' to read data received from port 5027 and insert it in my database, i want know   is there a possible way to read data received from specific port(in my case 5027) using C#?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly when you receive messages using the `HTTP` or `HTTPS` protocol, you can use the `HTTPListener` if you want to be a server, or use `HTTPClient` - if client. In case, when communication occurs using a different protocol, you can use a lower level api: `TcpListener`/`TcpClient`.

For a more complete answer, please explain, do you expect to read data from an external server and for this you need to connect to its port 5027?
Or do you want to be a server, listen the port and process received data?

References:

- [TCPListener](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.accepttcpclient(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [HTTPListener](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [TCPClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [HTTPClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

hope this will help you

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace MyTcpListener
    {
        interface ITcpListener : IDisposable
        {
            event ConnectionCreatedHandler OnConnectionCreated;
            event DataReceivingHandler OnDataReceiving;
            event DataReceivedHandler OnDataReceived;
            event ResponseSendingHandler OnResponseSending;
            event ResponseSentHandler OnResponseSent;
            event ErrorHandler OnError;

            object Tag { get; set; }

            void StartListening(string host, int port);
            void Dispose();
        }
    }


    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Sockets;

    namespace MyTcpListener
    {
        public delegate void ConnectionCreatedHandler(object sender, TcpConnectionEventArgs e);
        public delegate void DataReceivingHandler(object sender, TcpConnectionEventArgs e);
        public delegate void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, TcpConnectionEventArgs e);
        public delegate void ResponseSendingHandler(object sender, TcpConnectionEventArgs e);
        public delegate void ResponseSentHandler(object sender, TcpConnectionEventArgs e);
        public delegate void DataSendingHandler(object sender, TcpConnectionEventArgs e);
        public delegate void DataSentHandler(object sender, TcpConnectionEventArgs e);
        public delegate void ErrorHandler(object sender, string message);

        class TcpListener : ITcpListener
        {
            public event ConnectionCreatedHandler OnConnectionCreated;
            public event DataReceivingHandler OnDataReceiving;
            public event DataReceivedHandler OnDataReceived;
            public event ResponseSendingHandler OnResponseSending;
            public event ResponseSentHandler OnResponseSent;
            public event ErrorHandler OnError;

            public ManualResetEvent processCompleted = new ManualResetEvent(false);

            public HubTcpListener()
            {

            }
            public object Tag { get; set; }

            public void StartListening(string host, int port) 
            {
                int bufferSize = 1024 * 1024 * 1;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                bool keppAlive = true;
                TcpConnectionEventArgs tcpServerConnectionEventArgs = new TcpConnectionEventArgs();
                IPAddress[] ipAddreses = Dns.GetHostAddresses(host);
                IPEndPoint ipEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddreses[0], port);
                Socket listenerSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                try
                {
                    listenerSocket.Bind(ipEndpoint);
                    listenerSocket.Listen(500);

                    tcpServerConnectionEventArgs.HandlerSocket = listenerSocket;
                    tcpServerConnectionEventArgs.ReceivedTime = DateTime.Now;

                    if (OnConnectionCreated != null) 
                    {
                        OnConnectionCreated(this, tcpServerConnectionEventArgs);
                    }

                    while (keppAlive) 
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            processCompleted.Reset();
                            listenerSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(HandleAcceptCallBack), listenerSocket);
                            processCompleted.WaitOne();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            if (OnError != null) 
                            {
                                OnError(this, ex.Message);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                throw;
                }
            }
            private void HandleAcceptCallBack(IAsyncResult asyndResult) 
            {
                processCompleted.Set();
                Socket listener = (Socket)asyndResult.AsyncState;
                Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(asyndResult);
                StateObject stateObject = new StateObject() { clientSocket = handler };

                TcpConnectionEventArgs tcpServerConnectionEventArgs = new TcpConnectionEventArgs();
                tcpServerConnectionEventArgs.ReceivedTime = DateTime.Now;
                tcpServerConnectionEventArgs.HandlerSocket = handler;
                tcpServerConnectionEventArgs.ReceivedData = "";

                if (OnDataReceiving != null)
                {
                    OnDataReceiving(this, tcpServerConnectionEventArgs);
                }
                handler.BeginReceive(stateObject.buffer, 0, StateObject.bufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(HandleReadCallBack), stateObject);
            }
            private void HandleReadCallBack(IAsyncResult asyncResult) 
            {

                string contents = string.Empty;
                StateObject state = (StateObject)asyncResult.AsyncState;
                Socket handler = state.clientSocket;
                int bytesLength = handler.EndReceive(asyncResult);

                TcpConnectionEventArgs tcpServerConnectionEventArgs = new TcpConnectionEventArgs();
                tcpServerConnectionEventArgs.ReceivedTime = DateTime.Now;
                tcpServerConnectionEventArgs.HandlerSocket = handler;

                if (bytesLength > 0)
                {
                    state.stringBuilder.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesLength));
                    contents = state.stringBuilder.ToString();
                    tcpServerConnectionEventArgs.ReceivedData = contents; ;
                    if (OnDataReceived != null)
                    {
                        OnDataReceived(this, tcpServerConnectionEventArgs);
                    }
                    Send(handler, contents);
                }
                else 
                {
                    handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.bufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(HandleReadCallBack), state);
                }
            }
            private void Send(Socket handler, string data) 
            {
                TcpConnectionEventArgs tcpServerConnectionEventArgs = new TcpConnectionEventArgs();
                tcpServerConnectionEventArgs.ReceivedTime = DateTime.Now;
                tcpServerConnectionEventArgs.HandlerSocket = handler;
                tcpServerConnectionEventArgs.ReceivedData = data;

                if (OnResponseSending != null)
                {
                    OnResponseSending(this, tcpServerConnectionEventArgs);
                    data = tcpServerConnectionEventArgs.ReceivedData;
                }

                byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
                handler.BeginSend(bytes, 0, bytes.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(HandleSendCallBack), handler);
            }
            private void HandleSendCallBack(IAsyncResult asyncResult) 
            {
                try
                {
                    Socket handler = (Socket)asyncResult.AsyncState;
                    int bytesSendLength = handler.EndSend(asyncResult);

                    TcpConnectionEventArgs tcpServerConnectionEventArgs = new TcpConnectionEventArgs();
                    tcpServerConnectionEventArgs.ReceivedTime = DateTime.Now;
                    tcpServerConnectionEventArgs.HandlerSocket = handler;

                    if (OnResponseSent != null)
                    {
                        OnResponseSent(this, tcpServerConnectionEventArgs);
                    }
                    handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                    handler.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            public void Dispose()
            {
                Dispose(true);
                GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
            }
            protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    if (this.processCompleted != null)
                    {
                        this.processCompleted.Dispose();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }



    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Sockets;

    namespace MyTcpListener
    {
        public class TcpConnectionEventArgs : EventArgs
        {
            public Socket HandlerSocket { get; set; }
            public DateTime ReceivedTime { get; set; }
            public string ReceivedData { get; set; }
            public long TransactionID { get; set; }
            public long ConnectorID { get; set; }
        }
    }

    namespace MyTcpListener
    {
        public class StateObject
        {
            public Socket clientSocket = null;
            public const int bufferSize = (1024 * 1024) * 1; // 1 MB
            public byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            public StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi,thank you for your response.
in your code you instantiate an object named 'StateObject'.where is the class called 'StateObject'??

Comment: I am sorry , my bad I forgot to post that class. Please get the below code.
namespace MyTcpListener
{
 public class StateObject
 {
  public Socket clientSocket = null;
  public const int bufferSize = (1024 * 1024) * 1; // 1 MB
  public byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
  public StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
 }
}